# Changing custom attribute on input field using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to change the attribute **data-slider-values** on an input field using jQuery (or JavaScript).

The input initially in the HTML is this:

```
<input id="nm" data-slider-values="1,2,3,6,12,24,32" type="text" />
```

Now I need to change it to `3,6,12,24`

I try this but no help in the frontend. It just stays as it is. Where might be the problem?

```
$("#depSelector").change(function () {
    if (this.value === 'denarPlus') {
        $("#nm").data("slider-values","3,6,12,24")
}

...
```

I also tried

```
$("#nm").attr("data-slider-values","3,6,12,24")
```

and still no luck.

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: It should work, can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Your `attr` version should work, can you post an [MCVE](/help/mcve)? (The `data` version wouldn't; `data` never *sets* `data-*` attributes.)

Comment: Can't reproduce http://jsfiddle.net/gw2kqsyc/

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me.

```
<input id="nm" data-slider-values="1,2,3,6,12,24,32" type="text" />
<script type="text/javascript">

    // displays 1,2,3,6,12,24,32
    alert( $("#nm").attr("data-slider-values" ) )

    $("#nm").attr("data-slider-values","3,6,12,24")

    // displays 3,6,12,24
    alert( $("#nm").attr("data-slider-values" ) )

</script>
```

Could your issue be that something else needs to reload the `data-slide-values` attribute value?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#nm").attr("data-slider-values","3,6,12,24")
```

This is a right way.

if it doesn't work, please check if (this.value === 'denarPlus') statement.
I think this code wasn't invoked.